# Shower puck light install

Tags: shower, light

I live in a condo and want to install a shower light. Will it be an issue to install a damp/wet rated light in our shower ceiling with plumbing above it?  In case if there is a leak from the above unit, is there a way to waterproof the wires and junction box that comes with the puck light?

Comment: Since you live in a condo (multiple dwelling unit or MDU) you'll need to hire a Licensed Electrician if you are in the USA, anyway. Rules in other countries may vary. The light will also need GFCI protection on th supply.